# Can \uput mimic \rput when they enclose a non-zero dimensional object?

Tags: pstricks

### Zero-dimensional objects

For zero dimensional objects, `\uput` can mimic `\rput` as illustrated in the following example.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
% the first angle in [] will be ignored when the labelsep = 0.
\uput{0}[0]{0}(2,3){\pscircle(1,1){1}}
\uput{0}[45]{45}(2,3){\pscircle[linecolor=red](1,1){1}}
\uput{0}[90]{90}(2,3){\pscircle[linecolor=blue](1,1){1}}
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\rput{0}(2,3){\pscircle(1,1){1}}
\rput{45}(2,3){\pscircle[linecolor=red](1,1){1}}
\rput{90}(2,3){\pscircle[linecolor=blue](1,1){1}}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

### Non-zero dimensional objects

The following is my attempt to mimic `\rput` with `\uput`. Unfortunately, I failed and gave up! I cannot move the center of `\object` to `(2,3)` when using `\uput` while I can do it with `\rput`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 

\newcommand\object[1][black]{%
\pspicture(3,2)
\psframe*[linecolor=#1](3,2)
\endpspicture
}
\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\uput{0}[0]{0}(2,3){\object}
\uput{1.5}[0]{0}(2,3){\object[yellow]}
\uput{-1.5}[0]{0}(2,3){\object[blue]}
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\rput{0}(2,3){\object}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: In my mental model, `\uput` should be superior compared to `\rput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible in general and makes no sense from the definition.

To mimic `\rput{0}(2,3){\object}` with `\uput{<labelsep>}[<direction angle>]{0}(2,3){\object}` is not possible by adjusting the `<labelsep>` and `<direction angle>`.

But one of the possible special cases is,

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\uput{0}[0](2,3){\object}
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\rput[l]{0}(2,3){\object}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: I want to discuss the case in which `\rput` uses its default node reference at its center. Can `\uput` mimic `\rput` in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your problem. If `\uput` could be the same as `\rput`then we had not define it ...

Comment: Shortly speaking, how to setup the `<labelsep>` and `<direction angle>` for `\uput{<labelsep>}[<direction angle>]{0}(2,3){\object}` to produce the same result as `\rput{0}(2,3){\object}`?

Comment: I think the current implementation of `<labelsep>` does not accept a negative value so  we cannot move in opposite direction.

Comment: no, that is not possible and makes no sense from the definition

Answer (score 1):

Just for adding extra information to the accepted answer. I just knew it several seconds ago.

`\nput` (instead of `\uput`) can mimic what `\rput` does for the non-zero dimensional objects (the second case in the question).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand\object[1][black]{%
\pspicture(3,2)
\psframe*[linecolor=#1](3,2)
\endpspicture
}
\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6)
\pnode(2,3){A}
\nput[rot=0,labelsep=-1.5]{0}{A}{\object[blue]}
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6) 
\rput{0}(2,3){\object}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```